# Can't get Google Ads metrics for manager account, can't get permission for client account

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am trying to access the metrics for client accounts using the Google Ads API, through the Python client.

Currently I'm using a modified version of the [`get_campaign_stats_to_csv.py`](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/master/examples/reporting/get_campaign_stats_to_csv.py) example, with the query:

```py
import datetime
last_three_days = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
query = """
    SELECT 
        customer.descriptive_name, 
        metrics.cost_micros 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE 
        segments.date > '{last_three_days}' 
        AND segments.date <= '{today}'""".format(
            last_three_days=last_three_days.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            today=datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

It requires the commandline argument `--customer_id=` of the account we're reporting on, used as follows:

```py
search_request.customer_id = customer_id # e.g., '--customer_id=1234567890'
```

The problem is that when I use my Manager account customer id `1234567890`, I get the error:

```
error_code {
    query_error: REQUESTED_METRICS_FOR_MANAGER
  }
  message: "Metrics cannot be requested for a manager account. To retrieve metrics, issue 
separate requests against each client account under the manager account."
}
```

Which I assume means using the client id. But when I use the client ID `0987654321`, I get the error:

```
error_code {
    authorization_error: USER_PERMISSION_DENIED
  }
  message: "User doesn\'t have permission to access customer. Note: If you\'re accessing a 
client customer, the manager\'s customer id must be set in the \'login-customer-id\' 
header. See https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/call-structure#cid"
}
```

[The link in the error message](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/call-structure#cid) leads to the following header:

[image: CID Section, Google Ads API]

Which brings me back to square one, where the API spits the dummy when I use the Manager Account ID.

I've checked out [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675633/google-ads-api-failed-with-status-permission-denied-user-doesnt-have-pe), but I think we're having different problems, as all my accounts have the red 'TEST ACCOUNT' flag next to them.

As a final note: there are two test client accounts, both which I've set up with quasi campaigns.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote that example.
You can set the client ID in the command line or the YAML file. It will not work if you use a manager account ID.

I know the terminology is confusing but that's what that API expects.

If you have any further issues with it, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't have the manager account number in the `google-ads.yaml`. Adding it fixed my problem when I use the client ID as the commandline line argument.

Here's a picture of where I added the manager account number..

[image: Perfect]

Answer (score 0):

My solution is list the customers that you have got access to, and aren't manager, the customer_id i passed to the request was login-customer-id i.e.

```
customer_id_query = """SELECT
customer_client.id
FROM customer_client
where customer_client.manager = false"""
request = SearchSearchAds360Request()
request.customer_id = login_customer_id
request.query = query
```

Make sure you print the ids, as it will help seeing if your access is correct, then do a loop on your initial query but this time specifying customer_id as the customer_client.id i.e.

```
for customer_id in customer_ids:
   query = """
    SELECT 
        customer.descriptive_name, 
        metrics.cost_micros 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE 
        segments.date > '{last_three_days}' 
        AND segments.date <= '{today}
        AND customer.id = {customer_id}'""".format(
            last_three_days=last_three_days.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            today=datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            customer_id=customer_id)
    request = SearchSearchAds360Request()
    request.customer_id = customer_id
    request.query = query
```